# Fetch a certain page of a pdf as an image from google drive

Tags: pdf, google-drive-api

I have some 10,000 pages of hand-written scanned documents in google drive in somewhere around 70 pdf documents.
I am making a spreadsheet index of these, with one row for each page where I make notes of what is on each page, by actually viewing those pages, reading it, and every fully typing it if required.

I need a link, which I can put in the spreadsheet, which when clicked opens up a certain page of the pdf as an image only, and not the entire pdf, the pdf is in google drive. Is there something like this possible in Google Drive? Or should I manually download all pdf, split it into images, and then re-upload and use that?
(example - java -jar pdfbox-app.jar PDFToImage -format jpg -quality 0.75 pdffile.pdf ; and then upload all this)

I have a feeling it must be possible because when we open the pdf in browser, it loads pdf pages one by one, it takes time but it opens it in some custom image+text format, so it must be exported. Also I know there is one image version for each google slide and link is stable, so there might be something for pdf also I was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There isn’t a parameter or feature to link a pdf page in Google Drive file viewer.
- Indeed as mentioned, you can link to a specific slide in Google Slides, however Google file types do have additional features.
- That’s not the case for PDFs for example. A workaround I can think of would be to create a comment for each page and each comment will have its own id.
  After creating the comment, you can click on the three vertical dots icon and click on Link to this comment.
- Alternatively, you can send feedback to Google (On file viewer page, click on three vertical dots icon and then Send feedback to Google) making sure to describe the proposed feature.